# ASIHttpRequest Log in Authentication issue

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, authentication, asihttprequest

I am trying to authenticate User name and Password with  a website ...

i am using ASIHttpRequest like this:

```
- (IBAction)fetchTopSecretInformation:(id)sender{
  Ustr = User.text;    //Ustr and Pstr are strings 
  Pstr  = Pass.text;

  NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.MySite/login/"]];
  ASIFormDataRequest *request1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url1];
  [request1 setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
  request1.delegate = self;
  request1.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES;

  [request1 setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
  [request1 setPostValue:User.text forKey:@"username"];
  [request1 setPostValue:Pass.text forKey:@"passwd"];
  [request1 setTimeOutSeconds:30];
  NSLog(@"Useer :%@",User.text);

  [request1 setDidFailSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchFailed:)];
  [request1 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchComplete:)];
  [request1 startAsynchronous];
}

- (IBAction)topSecretFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error sending request to the server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}

- (IBAction)topSecretFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest{
  int statusCode = [theRequest responseStatusCode];
  NSString *statusMessage = [theRequest responseStatusMessage];

  NSString *strResponse = [[theRequest responseString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
  NSString *strFinal = [self flattenHTML:strResponse];
  NSLog(@"Response :%@",strFinal);
  NSLog(@"StatusCode: %d", statusCode);
  NSLog(@"StatusMessage: %@", statusMessage);
}
```

I get the Response in NSLog like this :

```
jQuery(function($) { $(".main").addClass("show-bg"); });

JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser.
You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.                

This is a demo store. Any orders placed through this store will not be honored or fulfilled.

                        +995 91 190601

            მოგესალმებით ელექტრონული წიგნების მაღაზიაში 

                        READERwill.com

    კალათა



                        კალათა GEL 0,00
                            სავაჭრო კალათა ცარიელია.

ჩემი ბიბლიოთეკა
სურვილები
რეგისტრაცია

.
.
.
.
.
```

and Status Code And status Message are

> StatusCode: 200
>   StatusMessage: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

What is this response and how can i use this for authentication

In my webservice if username and password is correct "Success" message is display and otherwise Fail message is display ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working for a new project then you should not use ASIHTTP Framework. Check instruction given in this link http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ It was last updated in 2011.

Just try to display only "strResponse" in NSLog . I think it should show response properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)topSecretFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
    NSString *statusMessage = [theRequest  responseData];
    NSLog(@"StatusCode: %d", statusCode);
    //at this methods you get authuntication
    //write code  here
}
```

Comment: I got statusCode :200 and statusMessage :Sattus Code : <3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733 432f2f44 like this

Comment: 'topSecretFetchComplete' method call when your authentication success. so you  write code here for redirect to other view which to be appear after authentication

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 200 response code is the normal response from a web server. If you are using forms authentication, as it appears you are, I would examine the cookies set in the response, as I would expect a session cookie to be returned on successful login. IIRC, ASIHTTPRequest will store the cookie by default and send it with subsequent requests automatically.

It *may* not matter what content you receive in the response as long as the cookie is set and some other error condition doesn't occur (like HTTP 401 or some other error), but this is highly dependent on your situation. You may need to parse the response for an error, and at this point, it appears that the server is either sniffing your request's agent string and detecting that your client doesn't support JavaScript, or it was expecting something like a form submitted in JSON format as part of an AJAX call, and assumes since that script failed that JavaScript isn't executing normally in your browser (which it isn't).

Right now you are submitting fields named `username` and `passwd` to the URL `https://www.MySite/login/`.

That appears to be the URL of a web page, not a web service. If you view the login form on the login page at that URL, does it have two fields for the credentials, and they use the name or ID `username` and `passwd`, e.g.:

```
<form action="https://www.MySite/login/" method="POST">
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="passwd" type="password" />
</form>
```

Or:

```
<form action="https://www.MySite/login/" method="POST">
    <input id="username" type="text" />
    <input id="passwd" type="password" />
</form>
```

Otherwise, if you are using a web service that communicates over SOAP or JSON, you will need to format your authentication request in that format instead of URL-encoded form data.

Comment: OK now i am using web login page directly but if i enter wrong password then also csll topSecretFetchComplete why ???

Comment: @Denny - Because the request completed properly, the server just returned a response that indicated the password was incorrect. This isn't an error, per se. The `ASIHTTPRequest` framework only calls the failure method if there was an error sending/receiving the request/response, not if there was a response from your app indicating login failed. It is up to you to parse the response for an error code/message indicating login failed. This is where it would be better to send your request to a web service that would fashion a response that reliably indicates the login failed in an expected format.